# Titanium: Tab & TabGroup - Custom "backgroundImage"

Tags: javascript, api, tabs, titanium, titanium-mobile

I've created custom images, both icon and background, for each of my tabs.

I tried using backgroundImage to add the images to my tabs, but it is not working.

Does anyone know what is wrong and how to resolve this?

Edit:
I created an entire new look for the tabGroup bar - background, icon, everything. So I'm not simply adding an icon.

```
var tab1 = Titanium.UI.createTab
({  
  backgroundImage:'yourImage.png',
  title:'Tab 1',            
  window:win1
});
```

Comment: show some code of "tried using backgroundImage to add the images to my tabs"

Comment: [yes, please do](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.UI.Tab.setBackgroundImage-method.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try this : In below scenario **yourImage.png** is in **Resources** folder

```
var tabGroup = Titanium.UI.createTabGroup();

var win1 = Titanium.UI.createWindow
({  
    url:'Tab1/Tab1.js',
    navBarHidden:false,   
    title:'Friend List'                 
});

var tab1 = Titanium.UI.createTab
({  
      icon:'yourImage.png',
      title:'Tab 1',            
      window:win1
});
```

Comment: I'm not trying to add an icon. I created an entire different look for the tabGroup bar.